# Network activity for user freezes after user change

Tags: networking, command-line, kubuntu, xorg

I have a persistent problem lasting in several Kubuntu versions:
I'm using 2 users on my computer to separate their histories and configuration.
To switch users I change X terminals using CTRL+ALT+F1 and CTRL+ALT+F2.
When I change the X terminal - the background network activity of the previous user gets frozen (i.e. downloads in browser breaks, YouTube music stops, and so on).

How can I fix this issue and let the background user keep normal network activity while the other user's terminal is foreground?

Thank you.